# Create a N x N matrix in Prolog (using lists?)

Tags: list, prolog

I want a have a matrix of size N x N in SWI-Prolog. A possible solution could be to create a list of N lists of size N, but now sure how to code this in Prolog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
length_list(N, L) :-
   length(L, N).

n_matrix(N, Xss) :-
   length(Xss, N),
   maplist(length_list(N),Xss).

maplist(_, []).
maplist(C, [X|Xs]) :-
   call(C,X),
   maplist(C, Xs).
```

To avoid the awkward auxiliary definition, we might use [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl):

```
n_matrix(N, Xss) :-
    length(Xss, N),
    maplist(N+\Xs^length(Xs,N),Xss).
```

Comment: exactly yesterday I was thinking how useful would be to have length_list/2 always available :)